# has_many関係を持つ親のモデルを子のモデルに基づいてソートする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

`Company` と `Disclosure`というモデルが有り `Company`

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :disclosures, dependent: :destroy
end
```

の関係になっています。

ここで`Disclosure`は`published_at`という`datetime`のカラムを持つのですが、複数の`Company`を`Disclosure`の`published_at`カラムの最新の物を用いてソートするにはどのような方法があるでしょうか？

現在は`Company`に`latest_disclosure_published_at`というソート用のカラムを追加し、`Disclosure`の更新時に`Company`側の情報を更新しています。

`Company`にカラムを追加せずにこのようなソートをするもっと良い方法はありますか？

### 追記

@yasu さんに教えて頂いた方法でローカルではできたのですが、サーバー上で試してみた所エラーが出てしまいました。

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "companies.code" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`
```

サーバー上とローカルで`Postgres`のバージョンが異なってしまっているのですが、それが原因なのでしょうか…？

```
Company.joins(:disclosures).
group('companies.id, companies.code').
select('companies.id, companies.code, MAX(disclosures.published_at) disclosure_published_at')
```

のように`select`するカラムを全て`group`で指定すれば呼び出せるようですが、できれば`*`で一括で指定したいです。

#### サーバー上(

psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.20

psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.2

Comment: PostgreSQLでyasuさんの書かれたような記法が通るようになったのは、9.1からだそう([PostgreSQL 9.1 の新機能](http://lets.postgresql.jp/documents/technical/9.1/1)「GROUP BY が MySQL 風に緩めに」の部分)なので、それより前のバージョンを使うのであれば`GROUP BY`(Railsの`group`メソッド)には`SELECT`で取得するカラムを全部指定する必要があります。(`*`は使えません。)と言うわけで、8.4.2(いくらなんでも古すぎるのでは?)を使うのであれば、「できれば`*`で一括で指定したい」は「できない」と言うことになるかと思います。

Comment: なるほど、`9.1`からだったのですね。これまで特に問題がなかったので古いバージョンのものを使っていたのですが、バージョンをあげることにします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN してこんな感じかなあ...

```
Company
  .joins(:disclosures)
  .group("companies.id")
  .select("companies.*, MAX(disclosures.published_at) disclosure_published_at")
  .order("MAX(disclosures.published_at)")
```

`MAX(disclosures.published_at)` の値を取るには特異メソッドの `disclosure_published_at` を使ってください。

**追記**

`GROUP BY` で指定した以外のカラムを `SELECT` で使うことは標準SQLとして正しくない方法で、私の回答があまりよくありませんでした。

カラムをいちいち指定するのも面倒なので、こんな感じの妥協案を。

```
company_cols = Company.column_names.map { |name| "#{Company.table_name}.#{name}" }
Company
  .joins(:disclosures)
  .group(company_cols)
  .select(*company_cols, "MAX(disclosures.published_at) disclosure_published_at")
  .order("MAX(disclosures.published_at)")
```

Comment: MAXをこういう風に使えばいいんですね、ありがとうございます。

Comment: すいません、ローカルでは教えて頂いた方法で解決したの解決済みにしたのですが、サーバー上ではエラーが出てしまったのでベストアンサーのチェックを外してエラーの詳細を質問に追記しました。

Comment: SQL-99以降の標準SQLでは、オプション仕様として、GROUP BY指定カラムに関数従属製のあるカラムはSELECTに記載できるような拡張を認めています(SQL optional feature T301)ので、「標準SQLとして正しくない」と言うのは不正確かと思います。「標準SQLでもオプション仕様なので互換性を考えるなら使用すべきでない」くらいでしょうか。